# Don't send all newsletters on the same day

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, newsletter

I've subscribed to the weekly newsletters of several Stack Exchange sites, mostly smaller ones that I'm interesting in but don't regularly visit. I just received all of them in my inbox at once.

I would prefer it if the newsletters for different sites were sent at different points during the week. It could give me something to read every day; with the current setup I'll probably skip a few of them.

Since (I assume) large sites are more likely to have subscribers, it might make sense to mainly ensure that they are spread out during the week, with the smaller sites distributed more randomly.

Alternately, schedules could be user-specific; either spread out during the week automatically or manually configured. This would require a different newsletter be generated each day, using a rolling one-week window, but this doesn't seem like it would be a prohibitively expensive operation.

### Related

- [Add an option for manually configurable newsletter dates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100569/134300)
- [Why are the newsletters being delivered at varied times & days?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100537/134300) (counter-request)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is done -- we'll no longer send all the newsletters on Mondays.

Instead, newsletters will be staggered across the workweek on a per-user basis: your first newsletter subscription will arrive on Tuesdays*, your second on Thursdays, third on Mondays, fourth Wednesdays, and fifth on Fridays. Your sixth subscription will loop back to Tuesdays, and so on.

<sup>* we [searched Google for "best day of week to send email newsletter"](http://www.google.com/search?q=best%20day%20of%20week%20to%20send%20email%20newsletter) and Tuesday seemed popular</sup>

Comment: Is there any chance of manually configurable dates?

Comment: @Kevin we'd consider it if there were a compelling reason.. what did you have in mind?

Comment: I don't really have a *compelling* reason; I just figured it would be useful (and reasonably painless to implement). I was thinking of manually grouping my newsletters by topic per day (eg. Stack Overflow and Programmers newsletters on Monday, Super User and Apple newsletters on Tuesday, etc). Do you think this is `feature-request`-worthy?

Comment: @Kevin Sure. It'd be interesting to know whether a lot of other people want this too.

Comment: [Doesn't seem very popular](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100569/add-an-option-for-manually-configurable-newsletter-dates) at the moment.

Comment: phew, less work for me :)

Comment: I really hope manually configurable dates and time. I usually receive these newsletters when I' m studying/working and don' t have many time for checking questions out.  After that, I just forget about it. I hope all newsletter can be set to be sent at a particular time at the weekend.