# Merge all the newsletters into one e-mail

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I would like to suggest that if a user is subscribed to more than one newsletter - which is probably a common occurance - then all the newsletters will be aggregated into one e-mail. If I'm marginally interested in 10 different topics, that means 10 different e-mails, which is a clutter. Just send it all together and make sure the formatting shows a clear distinction between the separate sites.

I've [suggested this on the newsletter feedback thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96758/weekly-site-newsletters/100107#100107) but it was suggested I create a new feature-request, so this is it.

Now, this suggestion is actually kind of orthogonal to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99782/dont-send-all-newsletters-on-the-same-day); maybe the best option is to have this aggregation is a toggle-able option.

Comment: I like the merge idea from @Oak as an *option*.  But I know some folks use their email to organize -- processing rules, flags, labels, what have you -- and this might be easier for that group of folks to have individual emails.

Comment: This should *definitely* be a toggle option, just like most newsgroups and mailing lists have a "digest" setting. Not everyone will want this, others will love it.

Comment: is this an option yet? I'm getting 10 different emails clogging up my inbox!