# Add an option for manually configurable newsletter dates

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, newsletter

As a follow-up to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99782/dont-send-all-newsletters-on-the-same-day), I think having user-settable dates for newsletter delivery would be a nice feature. Seeing as the newsletter already automatically cycles through days for delivery, letting users choose *their own* dates would be quite useful, in my opinion at least.

One use for this could be to sort newsletters by topic. At the moment, my Stack Overflow newsletter is being delivered on Thursdays, and my Programmers newsletter on Tuesdays. I would prefer if I could set both to be delivered on Monday (*Programming Mondays*, if you may). Also, I'm sure at least some people would find it useful to get all their newsletters sent on one day instead of spread out throughout the week (the way that the newsletters originally functioned).

Just my 2¢ worth.

Comment: Aww, nobody likes settable dates?

Comment: I misunderstood this originally; this is essentially a way to counteract http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99782/dont-send-all-newsletters-on-the-same-day . Which I guess is useful, but now this is getting unnecessarily complicated

Comment: *Counteract* wasn't quite what I was going for – more like *supplement* it (since the dates already cycle, I figured it would be useful if they were also user-configurable).

Comment: I don't agree with this request but your comment made me laugh...so no -1 :D

Comment: this is kind of a "don't make me think", isn't it?

Comment: @Jeff I would say *convenience*, but yes, I suppose it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything *wrong* with this idea, but we tend to err on the side of fewer configuration settings when we can get away with it, hence the [status-declined].